# How to save value from a Date Input Field in Laravel?

Tags: angularjs, html, date, laravel, datepicker

I cant seem to figure out how to save a date coming from a **date input field**. Whenever I try submit, the date's format is pretty weird. It always goes something like this:

```
Wed Jun 17 2015 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)
```

and saving it on my DB gets messy. I need to use Carbon to make it work.

**Is there a way to do save date from a Date Input Field flawlessly? If so, how?**

Comment: What format do you want for your php ?

Comment: I think you should first convert that string to a DateTime object, if it isn't an object already, and then format it to whatever format you need. Here are some examples http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php

Comment: I wanted the format "Y-m-d H:i:s" fot the DB. @MathieuBertin

Comment: I tried that too @Flavio. Problem is, I return the saved object to angular like so:

$event->save();
return $event;

By converting it to DateTime object, the returned date value to angular will be a date time object instead of a regular date.

Comment: so what's the problem? it seems like you already figure out how to save a date from an input which is the topic of your question. If you want to display that saved value, there are functions to convert a Date Time object to a string, here are some examples http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php

Comment: I am also struggling with this. I can convert the string one way or another to save it, but I'm attempting to find a clean solution. Laravel offers clean ways to save all post data to your new object and only populate the fillable properties.. the problem becomes that angularjs is going to send any date objects as the string you showed in your original post. My thought currently is that angularjs should have something in place to convert all incoming datetime strings to objects and all outgoing date objects to the MySQL DateTime string format- but I can not for the life of me get that to work.